# Internet Explored messing with my Photoshop template

Tags: dreamweaver, photoshop

I'm not good at all this website creating. But i need my web portfolio for graphic design. So i created template on photoshop. Sliced it. And saved for web. Then i opened it in Dreamweaver. All i did rollover for my buttons. And here how it looks in IE

stormilloart.com

check it in Opera, Safari, Firefox - looks perfect. But in Internet Explorer ist all messed up. Maybe there is a fix. Please help me out.

Comment: Get used to it that takes more time to adjust website to IE than to create it from scratch for every other **normal** browser.

Answer (score 0):

When you put images inside anchor tags, IE adds border around it. But Photoshop takes exact width and height of the sliced images. Because of the border added around the images, it creates layout issue.

To fix this, remove border around images inside anchor tags.

Add following code in head section.

```
<style>
    a img {
        border-width : 0;
    }
</style>
```